# Help interpreting a javascript Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have found the following expression which is intended to modify the id of a cloned html element e.g. change `contactDetails[0]` to `contactDetails[1]`:

```
var nel = 1;
var s = $(this).attr(attribute);
    s.replace(/([^\[]+)\[0\]/, "$1["+nel+"]");
    $(this).attr(attribute, s);
```

I am not terribly familiar with regex, but have tried to interpret it and with the help of [The Regex Coach](http://weitz.de/regex-coach/) however I am still struggling. It appears that `([^\[]+)` matches one or more characters which are not '`[`' and  `\[0\]/` matches `[0]`. The `/` in the middle I interpret as an 'include both',  so I don't understand why the author has even included the first expression.

I dont understand what the $1 in the replace string is and if I use the Regex Coach replace functionality if I simply use [0] as the search and [1](http://weitz.de/regex-coach/) as the replace I get the correct result, however if I change the javascript to `s.replace(/\[0\]/, "["+nel+"]");` the string s remains unchanged.

I would be grateful for any advice as to what the original author intended and help in finding a solution which will successfully replace the a number in square brackets anywhere within a search string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Find**

```
/           # Signifies the start of a regex expression like " for a string
([^\[]+)    # Capture the character that isn't [ 1 or more times into $1
\[0\]       # Find [0]
/           # Signifies the end of a regex expression
```

**Replace**

```
"$1["       # Insert the item captured above And [
+nel+       # New index
"]"         # Close with ]
```

To create an expression that captures any digit, you can replace the `0` with `\d+` which will match a digit 1 or more times.

```
s.replace(/([^\[]+)\[\d+\]/, "$1["+nel+"]");
```

Comment: Thanks, really nice explanation. It is not working for me though the following alerts contact[0]:
var nel = 1;
var s = "contact[0]";
s.replace(/([^\\[]+)\\[\d+\\]/, "$1["+nel+"]");
alert(s);

Comment: var s = s.replace(...) will do the trick.  You need to assign a replace to a variable.  Strings are not modified in place.

Answer (score 2):

The `$1` is a backreference to the first group in the regex. Groups are the pieces inside `()`. So, in this case `$1` will be replaced by whatever the `([^\[]+)` part matched.

If the string was `contactDetails[0]` the resulting string would be `contactDetails[1]`.

Note that this regex only replaces 0s inside square brackets. If you want to replace any number you will need something like:

```
([^\[]+)\[\d+\]
```

The `\d` matches any digit character. `\d+` then becomes any sequence of at least one digit.

But your code will still not work, because Javascript strings are immutable. That means they can't be changed once created. The `replace` method returns a new string, instead of changing the original one. You should use:

```
s = s.replace(...)
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand now an therefore understand that this should be working, however it is not. I have extracted this code and altering to set var s = ContactData[0], I've place it into a vanila html file within a script block, but after the replace s is unchanged. Any ideas what is happening?

Comment: when you say `s = ContactData[0]`, you mean `s = "ContactData[0]"` right? It's the string whose contents are `ContactData[0]` not the value at index 0 of the `ContactData[0]` array?

Comment: Addendum: ... of the `ContactData` array

Comment: Sorry yes you are correct and I had included the "" within my code.

Answer (score 1):

looks like it replaces arrays of 0 with 1.

For example:   array[0]  goes to  array[1]

Explanation:

([^[]+) -  This part means save everything that is not a [ into variable $1
[0]/      -  This part limits Part 1 to save everything up to a [0]

"$1["+nel+"]" -  Print out the contents of $1 (loaded from part 1) and add the brackets with the value of nel.  (in your example nel = 1)

Answer (score 0):

Square braces define a set of characters to match.  `[abc]` will match the letters a, b or c.

By adding the carat you are now specifying that you want characters not in the set.  `[^abc]` will match any character that is not an a, b or c.

Because square braces have special meaning in RegExps you need to escape them with a slash if you want to match one.  `[` starts a character set, `\[` matches a brace. (Same concept for closing braces.)

So, `[^\[]+`  captures 1 or more characters that are not `[`.

Wrapping that in parenthesis "captures" the matched portion of the string (in this case "contactDetails" so that you can use it in the replacement.

`$1` uses the "captured" string (i.e. "contactDetails") in the replacement string.

Answer (score 0):

This regex matches "something" followed by a `[0]`.
"something" is identified by the expression `[^\[]+` which matches all charactes that are not a `[`. You can see the () around this expression, because the match is reused with $1, later. The rest of your regex - that is `\[0\]` just matches the index [0]. The author had to write `\[` and `\]` because [ and ] are special charactes for regular expressions and have to be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

$1 is a reference to the value of the first paranthesis pair. In your case the value of

```
[^\[]+
```

which matches one or more characters which are not a '['

The remaining part of the regexp matches string '[0]'.

So if s is 'foobar[0]' the result will be 'foobar[1]'.

Answer (score 0):

`[^\[]` will match any character that is not `[`, the '+' means one or more times. So [^[]+ will match contactDetails.  The brackets will capture this for later use. The '\' is an escape symbol so the end `\[0\]` will match `[0]`.  The replace string will use $1 which is what was captured in the brackets and add the new index.

Answer (score 0):

Your interpretation of the regular expression is correct. It is intended to match one or more characters which are not `[`, followed by a literal `[0]`. And used in the `replace` method, the match would be replaced with the match of the first grouping (that’s what `$1` is replaced with) together with the sequence `[` followed by the value of `nel` and `]` (that’s how `"$1["+nel+"]"` is to be interpreted).

And again, a simple `s.replace(/\[0\]/, "["+nel+"]")` does the same. Except if there is nothing in front of `[0]`, because in that case the first regex wouldn’t find a match.